# function parameters, polymorphism

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code. I was wondering if there was a way to modify foo(A a) so that calling it would have the result as in the commented code below, but without overloading.

```
class A { 
  public: virtual void print() { std::cout << "A\n"; } };
class B : public A {
  public: virtual void print() { std:cout << "B\n"; }
};

void foo( A a ) { a.print(); } // How to modify this, so it chooses to use B's print()?
// void foo( B a ) { a.print(); } // now, this would work! 

int main( void ) { 
  A a; 
  foo( a ); // prints A
  B b;
  foo(b);  // prints A, but I want it to print B
}
```

Is this possible at all? If not, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must take the argument via reference (or pointer, but you don't need pointers here), otherwise the object gets sliced.

```
void foo(A& a) { a.print(); }
```

Comment: I wonder, is slicing the problem, or the fact that a copy is made?

Comment: Print should probably be a const-method then foo could accept a const-reference. [For Zaviour's benefit]

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem! Coming from java I had no idea about object slicing.